# Piecewise in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble coming up with a dragable code for this project.
[image: example]

Anything 100 or under is simple, I just used `=IFS(H6<E7,H6*F6)`
But above 100, I'm not sure what to do. If I hand coded it at 600, it would be (100 *2 + 400 *4 + 100 *6).

I'm drawing a blank on what I should do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with either `SUMIF` or `SUMPRODUCT` and an array formula. Google progressive pricing excel and you'll find samples.

Comment: That's a tough one. I'd flip it on its head and, given an input, try to come up with a formula that calculates the number of units for each rate; given 180 units that's 100 at the 0-100 rate, 80 at the 100-500 rate, and 0 for all others; add these up and you got the payment calculated. So 100-500 would be the greater value between 0 and N (180) minus the previous upper bound (100), times the rate. 500-1000 the same between 0 and N minus the previous upper bound (500), times the rate, and so on. *Then* try to refactor into a single formula!

Comment: Something like it, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very interesting lookup problem here! I've given it a few thoughts and came up with something that should help.

I've laid out the brackets horizontally, like this:

```
        0    100    500    1000
   40
  101
 1500
 6000
13000
  600
```

I have the inputs in column H, column I is left blank, and the brackets begin in column J.

So first we lookup the unit price per bucket. Easy enough, a plain old VLOOKUP will do. So J6 has this:

```
=VLOOKUP(J$5,$D$6:$F$9,3,TRUE)
```

Underneath this, in row 14, I've made a copy of this range, this time to calculate the number of units that belong under each bucket. This one was fun to come up with and could probably be simplified, but here's what I have in J14:

```
=MAX(0,MIN(MAX(0,$H14-J$5),VLOOKUP(J$5,$D$6:$E$9,2,FALSE)-SUM($I14:I14)))
```

Then I made another copy underneath to just multiply the two tables, so I have this in J22:

```
=J14*J6
```

By making the sum of the amounts under each bracket, we get what we're looking for:

- 40 => 80$
- 101 => 204$
- 1500 => 9800$
- 6000 => 54800$
- 13000 => 124800$
- 600 => 2400$

So, with a little bit of clean-up the helper ranges can certainly be removed, but then it becomes a monster formula that's pretty hard to tweak and/or debug later - whether the best solution is to do that or keep the helper ranges (and move or hide them, perhaps), is up to you!

Slight little edit, for the lookups to work you either need one more top bracket, or to have something like 9999999 as the upper bound for the "1000+" bracket.