# Vlookup from matrix, but there is some value ranges

Tags: excel, vba

we have a matrix table in which rows and columns are ranged values, f.e.:

[image]

In other table we have different values and sales. Now we need to add formula that returns for us correct value from matrix. Is there any way to do that? IF function is not suitable because above is an example table, in reality those values and sales ranges are much more. Maybe some VBA solutions?

[image]

Comment: From first sight, I would say you need somehow to combine a VLookup (for the row) and a HLookup  (for the column) function. As I hate complicated formulas, I would go for a VBA solution, but it's likely also possible with formulas

Comment: Feels somewhat similar to [this somewhat recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72735638/1188513) from someone else. Could the answer there help?

Comment: Are any of these numbers decimal numbers in your real case? Shouldn't it be `<=200` and `between 201 and 300` (similarly for the column)? Could you present your data with row and column headers so we don't have to make up where it is located?

Comment: @VBasic2008 i upload file example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L9zFCWhMkoYwdEdSN7gtKsnaV5ozmAFb/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117205053324523386963&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @VBasic2008 in real case in a rows there is an AGE ranges and in columns - SALES ranges.

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup in Value Ranges

[image]

```vb
Sub LookupValueRanges()
    
    ' Matrix
    Const MATRIX_WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const MATRIX_FIRST_CEll_ADDRESS As String = "B3"
    Dim SalesArray() As Variant
    SalesArray = VBA.Array(200, 300, 400) ' add more!
    Dim AgeArray() As Variant
    AgeArray = VBA.Array(5, 10, 20) ' add more!
    ' Sales & Age
    Const SALES_WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SALES_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B11"
    Const AGE_COLUMN As String = "A"
    ' Result
    Const RESULT_COLUMN As String = "C"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Matrix
    
    Dim wsMatrix As Worksheet
    Set wsMatrix = wb.Worksheets(MATRIX_WORKSHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim fcMatrix As Range
    Set fcMatrix = wsMatrix.Range(MATRIX_FIRST_CEll_ADDRESS)
    
    Dim SalesUpper As Long: SalesUpper = UBound(SalesArray)
    Dim AgeUpper As Long: AgeUpper = UBound(AgeArray)
    
    Dim rgMatrix As Range ' '+1' for zero-based, and '+1' for if greater than
    Set rgMatrix = fcMatrix.Resize(AgeUpper + 2, SalesUpper + 2)
    
    Dim MatrixData() As Variant: MatrixData = rgMatrix.Value
    
    ' Sales & Age
    
    Dim wsSales As Worksheet
    Set wsSales = wb.Worksheets(SALES_WORKSHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim fcSales As Range: Set fcSales = wsSales.Range(SALES_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    Dim rgSales As Range: Set rgSales = SetColumn(fcSales)
    Dim SalesData() As Variant: SalesData = GetColumnRange(rgSales)
    
    Dim rgAge As Range: Set rgAge = rgSales.EntireRow.Columns(AGE_COLUMN)
    Dim AgeData() As Variant: AgeData = GetColumnRange(rgAge)
    
    ' Result
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rgSales.Rows.Count
    Dim ResultData() As Variant: ReDim ResultData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Loop.
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim mrIndex As Long
    Dim mcIndex As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Age
        cValue = AgeData(r, 1)
        If VarType(cValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            For n = 0 To AgeUpper
                If cValue <= AgeArray(n) Then Exit For
            Next n
            mrIndex = n + 1
            ' Sales
            cValue = SalesData(r, 1)
            If VarType(cValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                For n = 0 To SalesUpper
                    If cValue <= SalesArray(n) Then Exit For
                Next n
                mcIndex = n + 1
                ResultData(r, 1) = MatrixData(mrIndex, mcIndex)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Result
    
    Dim rgResult As Range
    Set rgResult = rgSales.EntireRow.Columns(RESULT_COLUMN)
    
    rgResult.Value = ResultData
    
End Sub

Function SetColumn(ByVal FirstCellRange As Range) As Range
    With FirstCellRange
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set SetColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
End Function

Function GetColumnRange(ByVal SingleColumnRange As Range) As Variant()
    With SingleColumnRange
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then ' one cell
            Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = .Value: GetColumnRange = Data
        Else ' multiple cells
            GetColumnRange = .Value
        End If
    End With
End Function
```